# Error in superSet(): 'list' object cannot be coerced to type 'double'

Tags: r, dplyr

I am doing a Qualitative Comparative Analysis (QCA) for the first time. For this purpose, I use the 'QCA' and 'setMethods' packages in R. After checking for necessary conditions (none is arguably necessary) I want to display sufficient conditions using 'superSubset()':

```
SUIN_regimechange <- superSubset(data = qca_total,
                      outcome  = "ep_outcome",
                      conditions = c ("antiplural_gov", "polarize", "presidentialism"),
                      relation = "sufficiency",
                      incl.cut = 0.9,
                      cov.cut = 0.6,
                      ron.cut = 0.5,
                      depth = 3)
```

This results in the following Error:

'Error in superSubset(data = qca_total, outcome = "ep_outcome", conditions = c("antiplural_gov",  :
'list' object cannot be coerced to type 'double''

I tried to solve the problem by unlisting all variables of the dataset like that:

```
qca_total$demreg_id <- unlist(qca_total$demreg_id)
qca_total$country_name <- unlist(qca_total$country_name)
qca_total$ep_progress <- unlist(qca_total$ep_progress)
qca_total$ep_progress <- unlist(qca_total$ep_outcome)
qca_total$polarize <- unlist(qca_total$polarize)
qca_total$antiplural_gov <- unlist(qca_total$antiplural_gov)
qca_total$presidentialism <- unlist(qca_total$presidentialism)
```

However, the error warning remains. Do you have any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this issue by:

```
    qca_total<- as.data.frame(qca_total)
```